# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2-3))$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Question. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2-2)(x^2-3))$?
I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ with $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}: \varphi(f(x))=f(\sqrt{2}), \ker(\varphi)=(x^2-2)$ and $im(\varphi)=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}\right\}$.

Is the following correct? $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]\to \mathbb{Q}:\phi(f(x,y))=f(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\ker(\phi)=((x^2-2)(x^2-3))$, $im\phi=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$?

Comment: No. If you take a field $F$, and two elements of positive degree $p,q\in F[x]$, then $F[x]/(pq)$ has zero divisors: the images of both $p$ and $q$ are nonzero, but their product is zero. So $F[x]/(pq)$ can never be a field. The kernel of your $\phi$ is wrong: $x^2-2$ vanishes, but is not in your description of the kernel; $y^2-3$ vanishes, but is not in your description of the kernel.

Comment: I get it. In fact, I just saw that $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(6)). $
I am curious to know what is the homomorphism that allows us to see that
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-6)$

Comment: @ErikD  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is NOT isomorphic $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6} )$.  It does contain $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6}) $

Comment: Urgh. Yes, like @DionelJaime says; it is true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, but it’s degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ so it cannot equal $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ (previous dumb comment deleted).

Comment: How about ${\bf Q}(x,y)/(x^2-2,y^2-3)$?